# Regex: Find Guid (with/without dashes and with/without delimeters) in a long string

Tags: c#, regex

How can I create my regex that can identify a Guid in any of these formats?

```
"bd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fc";
"bd1a40dbf47c4bada7f80d54d854f6fc";
"something bd1a40dbf47c4bada7f80d54d854f6fc";
"something bd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fc";
"somethingbd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fc";
"somethingbd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fcsomething";
```

I've been trying my hand at this:

> ^[{|(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-{3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[)|}]?|[{|(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}([0-9a-fA-F]{4}){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[)|}]?$

But it isn't working for all cases. TryParse() method only works for first 2 cases.

Please help.

Comment: Well, try [`[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-?[0-9a-fA-F]{12}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b8%7d-%3f%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b4%7d-%3f%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b4%7d-%3f%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b4%7d-%3f%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b12%7d&i=bd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fc%0d%0abd1a40dbf47c4bada7f80d54d854f6fc%0d%0asomething+bd1a40dbf47c4bada7f80d54d854f6fc%0d%0asomething+bd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fc%0d%0asomethingbd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fc%0d%0asomethingbd1a40db-f47c-4bad-a7f8-0d54d854f6fcsomething)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

> In its canonical textual representation, the sixteen octets of a UUID
>   are represented as 32 hexadecimal (base 16) digits, displayed in five
>   groups separated by hyphens, in the form `8-4-4-4-12` for a total of 36
>   characters

Then regex would be:

```
{?\w{8}-?\w{4}-?\w{4}-?\w{4}-?\w{12}}?
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGCC3n/1)

Comment: this is gold! thanks. can't believe i was making it so complicated than it needed to be.